# Error: Fixture "activityLogPage" has unknown parameter "TestRailController"

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a bit of code here that keeps failing due to Error: Fixture "activityLogPage" has unknown parameter "TestRailController", I am sure this is user error on my end but I cant quite figure it out. Below this is the TestRailController I am trying to call.

activitylogpage.ts --->

```
import { ActivityLogSelectors } from '../../specs/types/activityLog.type';
import { Page } from '@playwright/test';
import test from '../../common/testrail/fixtures';


export const activityLogSelectors: ActivityLogSelectors = {
  datasource_id: 'label[for^=datasource_id]',
  categories: 'label:has-text("Access Control: Authentication")',
  policy: 'input[id^=downshift]',
};

type ActivityLogFixtures = {
  activityLogPage: Page;
};

const activityLogTest = test.extend<ActivityLogFixtures>({
  activityLogPage: async ({ page, TestRailController }, use) => {
    TestRailController.startNewTest('1');
    
    await page.goto('/');
    await page.waitForURL(/risk-posture/i);
    await page.click('a:has-text("Activity Log")');

    await page.waitForSelector('text=Clear');

    await use(page);
  },
});

export default activityLogTest;
```

fixtures.js. --->

```
const base = require('@playwright/test');
const TestRailController = require('./testrail.interface.js');
module.exports = base.test.extend({
    // https://playwright.dev/docs/test-advanced/#testinfo-object
    testrailController: async ({ browser }, use, testInfo) => {
        const testrailController = new TestRailController();
        await use(testrailController);
        for (const context of browser.contexts()) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
            await context.close();
        }
        // only update testrail when process.env.APP_VERSION is valid string
        // testInfo is needed here because this below part will be run before test started while testInfo is null
        // use testrail feature for saving test-result
        if (appVersion && testInfo) {
            await testrailController.updateAllTests(testInfo);
        } else {
            console.log('Env var APP_VERSION or testInfo is not available, will not update testrail case');
        }
    },
});
```